# How to execute a string containing condition in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am filtering a `DataFrame` inside a function. I get multiple conditions as `string` arguments which I have to employ to filter the `DataFrame`. [`exec()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec) usually helps to execute a string expression, but I am not able to fine tune it for the `DataFrame`.

Here is a small miniature example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[30,60,90,40],'B':['X','X','X','Y']})
print(df)
      A  B
  0  30  X
  1  60  X
  2  90  X
  3  40  Y
```

Now, the code below gives an error naturally. My question is how we can evaluate this string `expression` in the function below like `exectable(expression)` and get the filtered `DataFrame`:

```
def func(df,cond1,cond2):
    expression = "(df.A "+cond1+") & (df.B"+cond2+")"
    print(expression) # This results in --> (df.A < 50) & (df.B == 'X')

    return df[expression]
func(df,"< 50"," == 'X'")
```

Desired output,

```
      A  B
  0  30  X
```

Comment: Have you tried `eval`?

Comment: It works. Many thanks. Just post one line answer and I will accept it. Since `exec()` did not work, so I couldn't forsee that `eval()` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is what you are looking for.

```
def func(df,cond1,cond2):
    expression = eval(f"(df.A {cond1}) & (df.B{cond2})")

    return df[expression]
```

Comment: True, but it exists and so has applications. Unless TS is not putting user's input into `eval` he is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Youi can use [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query):

```
import pandas as pd

def func(df,cond1,cond2):
    expression = "(A "+cond1+") & (B"+cond2+")"
    return df.query(expression)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[30,60,90,40],'B':['X','X','X','Y']})
print( func(df,"< 50"," == 'X'") )
```

Prints:

```
    A  B
0  30  X
```